# How do I get WPF usercontrols to derive from a common base

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a number of user controls in my application call then View1, View2...
I want them all to look like

```
public View1 : ViewBase<View1ViewModel>
```

and ViewBase looks like

```
public class ViewBase<T> : UserControl where T : new()  
{  

    private T vm = new T();

    public T ViewModel
    {
        get { return vm; }
        set { vm = value; }
    }
    public ViewBase()
    {
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

Now this of course does not work Since my Views are all derived form UserControl elsewhere in the generated files from the xaml.. 
Do I have any options to get this to work. ViewBase must be a generic type that accepts the viewmodel that the View will expose. I thought it was rather clever myself :-) but will it not work ?

Comment: ok awesome I figured it out

Comment: you can change the XAML in the user control class as follows , basically indicate what you are deriving from and pass in the generic type, rebuild all and coolness !

<LV:ViewBase x:TypeArguments="LVM:CastServerViewModel" x:Class="MediaCastShell.Views.CastServerView"            
             xmlns:LV="clr-namespace:MediaCastShell.Views"
             xmlns:LVM="clr-namespace:MediaCastShell.ViewModels"
>

</LV:ViewBase>